# Cannot Compile Assembly on my Mac!

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

```
$ gcc -m32 hw3.c -o hw3
Undefined symbols:
  "i", referenced from:
      _main in ccuNMbgT.o
      _main in ccuNMbgT.o
     (maybe you meant: _i, _main , cstring=hey, supposed to supply an integer argument , cstring=after multiply, value is %d
 , _i$non_lazy_ptr , _printf , _environ , _atoi , _exit )
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm doing assembly with some C. I'm trying to compile an example that worked on Ubuntu compiled using `gcc`, but its not working on my Mac terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It told you the problem and gave you the solution ("maybe you meant: ...").  Whether C symbols get underscores prepended to them in assembler is one of those things that is highly platform-dependent; on OS X they do, so when referring to a variable named "i" in C you must call it "_i" in assembler.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't really understand the error, thanks for your help!